# Alert about bounced emails using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, email, email-bounces

I have a Spring Boot application that sends emails. For any action that requires notification, a `Mail` instance is created with status `PENDING` in the database and a job is run to send the pending emails every minute. The status of the `Mail` instances are set as `PENDING`, `SENT` or `FAILED`.

```
try {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
    props.put("mail.smtp.from", myEmailAddress);
    props.put("mail.smtp.timeout", 2000);

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
    });

    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
    MimeMultipart content = getContent(mail, message, username);
    message.setContent(content);
    Transport.send(message);
    mail.setStatus(MailStatus.SENT);
    mailService.save(mail);
} catch (MailConnectException mce) {
    mail.setStatus(MailStatus.FAILED);
    mailService.save(mail);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // other actions
}
```

Now, this works fine if a valid email id is provided. But when the receiving email address is a non-existent one like `somerandomname@gmail.com`, there are no exceptions thrown. From what I read from similar questions in SO and elsewhere, I understand that mail sending is an asynchronous process and hence there is no way to determine that a given email is existing or not (or other issues like Inbox full). That is why after the `Transport.send(message);` statement, the `mail.setStatus(MailStatus.SENT);` statement will always be executed irrespective of the email address being present. Later the mail will actually be attempted to be sent and I get an email in `myEmailAddress` with content like the following:

> The response from the remote server was: 550 5.1.1
>   somerandomname@gmail.com User unknown

Okay, accepted until this point. But now I need a way to alert the user that the email couldn't be sent because they entered an invalid email so that they can update their email. More specifically, I need to set the status of the `Mail` instance to `FAILED`. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: what i know of it is impossible to know if an email has landed in someones inbox. The only thing you can check is as you have done, that your service sends the email which it does. That the recipient has actually received the email is up to the user to provide a correct address. Not your service! Thats why you see sites asking users every 6 months "is this your current email address" so that people keep updated email addresses. So im sorry but i think you are out of luck.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf thanks for your comment. My problem is that these email addresses don't even have an account in the application. These may be a bunch of email addresses I have imported using a csv file to whom I'd like to email when a new product is added to the application. So unless the email sending fails, and I specifically look at the Undelivered emails in `myEmailAddress`, there is no way to tell that an invalid email address has been added. Since the Undelivered emails all come to `myEmailAddress`, is there anyway to trigger an api when such an email arrives? Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a service like AWS SES to send your mail, you can receive notifications about bounces (and complaints) either simply as notifications for a human to read, or as programmatic triggers that could be used to call an alert endpoint on your spring boot server, for example through AWS Lambda. There are other services that may be able to do the same, such as SendGrid.

Answer (score 0):

Your Spring Boot application would have to retrieve the notifications (an email itself) from your inbox corresponding to the sender address of the initial email. There are various options how to achieve this:

- Use a service with provides callbacks (triggers) for incoming messages as mentioned by Benjamin
- Poll your inbox using a standard protocol like POP or IMAP

Hint for the second option: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/mail.html#mail-inbound